# Are the three phrases the same in meaning?

Tags: phrase-usage

Are the three phrases identical in meaning?

1. to keep healthy
2. to stay healthy
3. to remain healthy

Comment: Note that only **to keep healthy** can be used transitively, as in: **To keep healthy animals**.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that they have the same meaning. In my experience, saying "to stay healthy" is most common.